# Filtering query results by custom (user-created) field values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The software I'm working on enables administrators to create custom fields to store arbitrary information about the user. The fields are stored in the table called `meta` and their per-user values are stored in table `meta_value` which references `user` and `meta` tables via foreign keys.

Simplified definition of tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idx_username` (`username`)
);

CREATE TABLE `meta` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `key` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `idx_key` (`key`)
);

CREATE TABLE `meta_value` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    `meta_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`meta_id`) REFERENCES `meta` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
    INDEX `idx_value` (`value`)
);
```

I'm implementing a search functionality where the user is able to search other users by the values of the custom fields. The search query (simplified) looks like this: `?firstName[eq]=Andrew&lastName[eq]=Johnson&cityName[like]=Minneapol`.

This query string should select all users with fields `firstName = 'Andrew'` AND `lastName = 'Johnson'` AND `city LIKE 'Minneapol%'`.

I've tried the obvious solution:

```sql
SELECT `user`.*
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `meta_value` ON `meta_value`.`user_id` = `user`.`id`
INNER JOIN `meta` ON `meta`.`id` = `meta_value`.`meta_id`
WHERE (
    CASE `meta`.`key`
        WHEN 'firstName' THEN `meta_value`.`value` = 'Andrew'
        WHEN 'lastName' THEN `meta_value`.`value` = 'Johnson'
        WHEN 'cityName' THEN `meta_value`.`value` LIKE 'Minneapol%'
    END
);
```

This query returns results where `firstName = 'Andrew'` OR `lastName = 'Johnson'` OR `cityName LIKE 'Minneapol%'` which is not the desired result.

I appreciate all the suggestions on how to solve this problem or the right way of doing it in case I'm not doing it right.

Please note that the table structure is not set in stone and can be changed so if you know a more appropriate way to structure data for this purpose please suggest it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u JOIN
     meta_value mv
     ON mv.user_id = u.id JOIN
     meta m
     ON m.id = mv.meta_id
WHERE ( (m.key = 'firstname' AND mv.value = 'Andrew') OR
        (m.key = 'lastName' AND mv.value = 'Johnson') OR
        (m.key = 'cityName' AND mv.value LIKE 'Minneapol%')
      )
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.key) = 3;
```

Comment: It seems to work, but I don't understand the structure of the query. First, we do the normal query that will return data which has `firstName = 'Andrew'` or `lastName = 'Johnson'` or `cityName LIKE 'Minneapol%'` and group the result by user IDs to remove duplicates. But then I don't understand how exactly the HAVING clause returns the data I need. Can you explain please?

Comment: @aicantar . . . The `HAVING` clause ensures that all three keys match.

Answer (score 1):

Add additional condition in loop:

```php
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `user` 
    WHERE 1=1';
...
foreach($request as $fieldKey => $data) {
    $query .= (' AND user.id IN (
    SELECT `user_id` 
        FROM meta_value
        JOIN `meta` ON meta.`id` = meta_value.`meta_id`
        WHERE meta_value.`value` ' . $data['operand'] . ' "' . $data['value'] . '"
            AND meta.`key` = "' . $fieldKey . '")');
}
...
```